# Filtering subjects below accuracy threshold in R

Tags: r, threshold

I have a data frame containing a list of subjects below a certain accuracy threshold (i.e 50% incorrect): [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxZpE.png).
I have another data frame containing all subjects (accurate and inaccurate) with all their data. Importantly, there are multiple rows per subject in this central data frame: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAUzv.png).

I need to remove the inaccurate subjects from the central data-frame in 2. How do I do this in R? I have already tried subset:

```
 filterdata<-subset(groupedmergedoutliers, subject==filtercorrectpercent$subject)
```

'groupedmergedoutliers' is the central subject data frame ; 'filtercorrectpercent'is the inaccurate subjects data frame;

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to subset data frames with `[` or with `subset()`?

Comment: I have tried subset, but it appears to be filtering more values than it should. I think the problem has to do with the fact that the central data frame contains multiple rows for each subject but the inaccurate subject data frame contains only one-row per subject.

Comment: Well, how are you trying it? We can probably make a slight correction...

Comment: Here is the code: filterdata<-subset(groupedmergedoutliers, subject==filtercorrectpercent$subject)

groupedmergedoutliers=central subject data frame ; 
filtercorrectpercent=inaccurate subjects data frame

Comment: Please edit the code into your question, it is not easy to read in the comments.

Comment: The question has been edited to reflect the code. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `==`, which tests for pairwise equality (e.g., is the first row of `df1$subject` equal to the first row of `df2$subject`, are the second rows equal, etc.). Consider

```
c(1, 1, 2, 3) == c(1, 2, 3, 4)
# [1] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Instead, you want to be testing if each row of `df1$subject` is in any row of `df2$subject`. We can use `%in%` for this:

```
c(1, 1, 2, 3) %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

filterdata <- subset(
    groupedmergedoutliers,
    subject %in% filtercorrectpercent$subject
)
```